# ffmpeg - replace all corrupted frames with a dummy

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing, video-encoding

I look for a solution on how to detect and then automatically replace all corrupted (or completely broken) frames with a black one.

I've already tried the following command, but the result is not quite what I actually need.

```
ffmpeg -err_detect ignore_err -i video-with-broken-frames.avi -c copy fixed.avi
```

This command detects and replaces all corrupted frames with the nearest good one. So that if I have 20 corrupted frames at the start of a video - they will be replaced with 21st good one. Well, what I need is to replace corrupted frames with some dummy, for instance with a black one. Or just some-how to indicate what that frame is broken and was copied.

Comment: same issue, would really like to know how to do that

Comment: Same issue, did anyone find a solution?